# The << operator in php for exampe 4<< 5

Tags: php

I found a question:

*What wll be output of following*

```
echo 4<< 5;
```

And the answer is `128`

But i could not understand the the logic behind this.

Comment: decimal `4` in binary is `00000100` (showing just 8 bits for simplicity)... `4 << 1` means shift those binary bits left `1` place to give binary `00001000` which is decimal `8`; `4 << 2` means shift those binary bits left `2` place to give binary `00010000` which is decimal `16`; `4 << 3` means shift those binary bits left `3` place to give binary `00100000` which is decimal `32`; etc

Comment: Thanks @MarkBaker  :) i got it now